# unable to launch pterodactyl wings due to fatal error

Tags: minecraft

I downloaded ubuntu recently and tried using pterodactyl wings for my minecraft server and after a reboot of my machine i can't launch wings again. here is what pops up

```
root@minecraft-server:/home/server# wings
 INFO: [Jul 22 00:55:23.937] writing log files to disk 
path=/var/log/pterodactyl/wings.log

                     ____
__ Pterodactyl _____/___/_______ _______ ______
\_____\    \/\/    /   /       /  __   /   ___/
   \___\          /   /   /   /  /_/  /___   /
        \___/\___/___/___/___/___    /______/
                            /_______/ 1.4.5

Copyright © 2018 - 2021 Dane Everitt & Contributors

Website:  https://pterodactyl.io
 Source:  https://github.com/pterodactyl/wings
License:  https://github.com/pterodactyl/wings/blob/develop/LICENSE

This software is made available under the terms of the MIT license.
The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included
in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

 INFO: [Jul 22 00:55:23.938] loading configuration from file config_file=/etc/pterodactyl/config.yml
 INFO: [Jul 22 00:55:23.939] configured wings with system timezone timezone=Etc/UTC
 INFO: [Jul 22 00:55:23.939] checking for pterodactyl system user username={997 997}
 INFO: [Jul 22 00:55:23.940] configured system user successfully gid=997 uid=997 username=pterodactyl
 INFO: [Jul 22 00:55:23.941] fetching list of servers from API
 INFO: [Jul 22 00:55:23.985] processing servers returned by the API total_configs=0
 INFO: [Jul 22 00:55:23.985] finished processing server configurations duration=621.87µs
 INFO: [Jul 22 00:55:23.989] configuring internal webserver host_address=0.0.0.0 host_port=8080 use_auto_tls=false us            e_ssl=false
FATAL: [Jul 22 00:55:23.990] failed to initialize the sftp server error=listen tcp 0.0.0.0:2022: bind: address alread            y in use
 INFO: [Jul 22 00:55:23.990] updating server states on Panel: marking installing/restoring servers as normal
FATAL: [Jul 22 00:55:23.993] failed to configure HTTP server error=listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8080: bind: address already in             use

Stacktrace:
listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8080: bind: address already in use
github.com/pterodactyl/wings/cmd.rootCmdRun
        /home/runner/work/wings/wings/cmd/root.go:347
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.1/command.go:854
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.1/command.go:958
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.1/command.go:895
github.com/pterodactyl/wings/cmd.Execute
        /home/runner/work/wings/wings/cmd/root.go:66
main.main
        /home/runner/work/wings/wings/wings.go:8
runtime.main
        /opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.16.5/x64/src/runtime/proc.go:225
runtime.goexit
        /opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.16.5/x64/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1371
```

I tried a lot of things even going back and redoing all the install commands but I'm lost and can't find a way to get out of this situation.

What should I do to make this all work?

Comment: I've never heard of wings, but the error indicates that port 8080 is being used by something else (do you have any other web applications running?). You should figure out what's using it and kill it. Or get wings to listen on a different port.

Comment: @HPierce well when i loggin into my machine local ip i have an nginx page popping up and "wings is supose to complete my web page who probably is running on 8080 so could this be the source of my problem ?

Comment: This question probably belongs on another site such as Super User

Comment: Is this a joke? I am not sure if this is not Spam, but anyway I seen there is a comunity on https://discord.com/invite/pterodactyl please ask your question there.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer can not allow for 2 different processes to use the same port. As seen in your stack trace, the server failed to boot since a different process is also using port 8080. The solution is to kill the other process, or reconfigure Pterodactyl to use a different port.

If you want to find out which processes are using that port, you can run `lsof -i :8080` [on Linux](https://mkyong.com/linux/linux-which-application-is-using-port-8080/). [If you are on Windows](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-check-which-process-is-using-port-8080-or-a), then run `netstat -aon | findstr 8080`, then use the PID (column on the right) in the following command- `tasklist | findstr <PID>`.